# Downloading files in Java and common errors

Tags: java, download, applet, io

I wrote a simple downloader as Java applet. During some tests I discover that my way of downloading files is not even half as perfect as e.g. Firefox's way of doing it.

My code:

```
InputStream is = null;
FileOutputStream os = null;
os = new FileOutputStream(...);
URL u = new URL(...);
URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
is = uc.getInputStream();
final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for(int count = is.read(buf);count != -1;count = is.read(buf)) {
    os.write(buf, 0, count);
}
```

Sometimes my applet works fine, sometimes unexpected things happen. E.g. from time to time, in the middle of downloading applet throws an IO exception or just lose a connection for a while, without possibility to return to current download and finish it.

I know that really advanced way is too complicated for single unexperienced Java programmer, but maybe you know some techniques to minimalise risk of appearing these problems.

Comment: What I/O exception do you get?

Comment: blahblahblahblahblah -- where's the stacktrace?

Comment: *not even half as perfect* - how do you measure perfection? (Just kidding.)

Comment: I didn't write it down - I'm sorry. It happens only from time to time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to resume your download.

If you get an IOException on reading from the URL, there was a problem with the connection.
This happens. Now you must note how much you already did download, and open a new connection which starts from there.

To do this, use `setRequestProperty()` on the second, and send the right header fields for "I want only the range of the resource starting with ...". See [section 14.35.2 Range Retrieval Requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) in the HTTP 1.1 specification. You should check the header fields on the response to see if you really got back a range, though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll use it. But what can I do to prevent and minimalise number of errors? I thought about sth like setting a longer time of waiting for data from server.

Comment: There is a `setReadTimeout` method on URLConnection, which might help. I didn't ever really have problems, which might be because I have a good internet connection and seldomly use URLConnection.